# How to easily test redux-observable epic that emits an action after 5 minutes?

Tags: testing, timer, rxjs, redux-observable

I have an epic that emits SOME_OTHER_ACTION when 5 minutes have passed after SOME_ACTION (using delay operator).
I want to use jest or sinon useFakeTimers method to be able to do the following: dispatch an action, wait 5 minutes and test if another action was dispatched.
I really don't want to use marble diagrams, or inject TestSchedulers.
I also don't want to wait 5 minutes of real time.

```
const timeBefore = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
store.dispatch(SOME_ACTION);
// wait 5 minutes
jest.runTimersToTime(5 * 60 * 1000);
expect(store.getActions()).toEqual([ SOME_ACTION, SOME_OTHER_ACTION ]);
expect(store.getActions()[1].time).toEqual(timeBefore + 5 * 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: can you elaborate on what the issue is? `jest.runTimersToTime()` should work.

Comment: But it doesn't, it never emits SOME_OTHER_ACTION. Although, if I mock delay operator like so: `Rx.Observable.prototype.delay = function () { return this }` it emits the action immediately (5 minutes don't pass)

Comment: Sorry! I can't help without knowing what exactly the problem is and how to reproduce it.

Comment: Can you make the timeout configurable (add it to payload) then test with say 100ms?

Comment: I probably can and I thought about that yesterday. That’s good solution for now, but imagine if I have a lot of epics that are delayed and I need to test them all. Run tests continuously. There has to be the way to mock timeouts...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I ended up doing is: replaced RxJS with [xstream](https://github.com/staltz/xstream), and used [adapter](https://github.com/vic/redux-observable-adapter-xstream) for redux-observable, modified my epics accordingly.
It turns out that Jest doesn't handle Date correctly when using fakeTimers, so I used [lolex](https://github.com/sinonjs/lolex) for fake timers.
See my [gist](https://gist.github.com/gazedash/0ca86e2617e3e679f967e5028ae1fb8c) for full example.
(I didn't find easy way to test or replace internal RxJS delay, so I had to use different reactive library).

```
clock.setTimeout(() => {
  expect(store.getActions()).toEqual([trainIncomingAction, reminderAction]);
  done();
}, 60 * 60 * 1001);
clock.runToLast();
```